# Добавление аудио трека в стрим в то время когда MediaRecorder в состоянии 'recording'

Tags: javascript, webrtc, webapi, mediarecorder

Я пытаюсь добавить mediaTrack в MediaStream при активной записи, когда MediaRecorder в состоянии 'recording'

Добавляю трек таким образом:

```
activeStream.addTrack(newAudioTrack)
```

После успешного добавления трека на объекте MediaRecorder срабатывает событие **onstop** и запись прерывается. Можно ли каким либо образом на лету добавлять треки и удалять не прерывая запись?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на этот вопрос от @chrisguttandin с англоязычной ветки мне помог.

You can use an AudioContext to create a fixed MediaStream that you can pass to the MediaRecorder. This allows you to change the input when recording.

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode = new MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode(audioContext);
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode.stream);
```

Let's say you have a MediaStream called initialMediaStream. You could connect it like that:

```
const mediaStreamAudioSourceNode = new MediaStreamAudioSourceNode(
    audioContext,
    { mediaStream: initialMediaStream }
);

mediaStreamAudioSourceNode.connect(mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode);
```

You can then start recording the initialMediaStream.

```
mediaRecorder.start();
```

Later on you can replace the initialMediaStream with anotherMediaStream.

```
const anotherMediaStreamAudioSourceNode = new MediaStreamAudioSourceNode(
    audioContext,
    { mediaStream: anotherMediaStream }
);

anotherMediaStreamAudioSourceNode.connect(mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode);
mediaStreamAudioSourceNode.disconnect();
```

You could even use GainNodes to apply a cross-fade between the two streams if that's what you want.